# Recursion vs fold efficiency

Tags: haskell, recursion, fold

In the well-known [Haskell tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules), the function that finds a value-by-key in an associative list is first defined like that:

```
findKey :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> Maybe v  
findKey key [] = Nothing  
findKey key ((k,v):xs) = if key == k  
                            then Just v  
                            else findKey key xs
```

However, the author then argues that this type of "textbook recursion" should better be implemented using a fold:

```
findKey key = foldr (\(k,v) acc -> if key == k then Just v else acc) Nothing
```

I found that confusing. Am I right that:

1. The `foldr`-based function will always traverse the whole list before producing a result, whereas the first one will immediately stop upon discovery?
2. As a consequence, the first function will work on an infinite list, whereas the second one won't?

It seems to me that the *really* equivalent definition would use a `scanr` instead and from that, take the first result that isn't `Nothing`. (?)

Comment: Try using the foldr-based version on an infinite list. Did you have to wait infinite time.for the result? If not, this version doesn't traverse the entire list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foldr` is defined such that

```
foldr cons z (x:xs) = cons x (foldr cons z xs)
```

so if `cons` doesn't use its second argument, its value isn't needed. Since Haskell is call-by-need, unneeded values are not evaluated.

So no, both formulations have the same laziness characteristics.

```
findKey key (x:xs)
  = foldr (\(k,v) r -> if key == k then Just v else r) Nothing (x:xs)
  = (\(k,v) r -> if key == k then Just v else r) x
      (foldr (\(k,v) r -> if key == k then Just v else r) Nothing xs)
  = case x of (k,v) -> if key == k then Just v else 
      (foldr (\(k,v) r -> if key == k then Just v else r) Nothing xs)
```

and so if `key == k` holds, the recursive call (to find out the `r`'s value) isn't triggered.

Comment: `foldr` with `-O2` often ends up being more performant than doing the same thing with manual recursion thanks to `fold/build` fusion.

Answer (score 4):

1. No, when the function `\(k,v) acc -> ...` is called by `foldr`, the recursive call to `foldr` is supplied as the second argument (i.e. `acc`). So, keeping in mind that Haskell is lazy, if `acc` isn't used (i.e. if the `if` condition is true), the recursive call does not happen and the traversal stops.
2. Both work fine with infinite lists.

Comment: @sepp2k Eventually I understood what you mean, thank you! Would you mind adding an example though? I am sure it will be useful for future readers.